# "JQuery Bottom Content Panel" Load as "hidden" instead of "show"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently trying to get this:
http://www.jqueryscript.net/layout/Creating-A-Toggable-Bottom-Content-Panel-Using-jQuery-CSS.html

To load as hidden and ready to be opened instead of already opened.  Below is the main.js code:

```
(function($) {

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    Panel.init();

    $(document).on('click', '.tab-controller', function() {
         Panel.togglePanel();
    });

});

var Panel = {

    isVisible : false,
    showMessage : null,
    hideMessage : null,
    animationDuration : 350,
    animationEasing : 'linear',

    init : function() {

    },

    showPanel : function() {
        $('.panel-wrapper').animate({
            bottom : 0
        }, Panel.animationDuration, Panel.animationEasing, function() {
            Panel.isVisible = true;
            Panel.updateTabMessage();
        });
    },

    hidePanel : function() {
        $('.panel-wrapper').animate({
            bottom : -(Panel.getAnimationOffset())
        }, Panel.animationDuration, Panel.animationEasing, function() {
            Panel.isVisible = false;
            Panel.updateTabMessage();
        });
    },

    togglePanel : function() {
        ((this.isVisible) ? this.hidePanel : this.showPanel)();
    },

    updateTabMessage : function() {
        if (this.isVisible) {
            $('.tab-controller .close').show();
            $('.tab-controller .show').hide();
        } else {
            $('.tab-controller .close').hide();
            $('.tab-controller .show').show();
        }
    },

    getAnimationOffset : function() {
        return $('.panel-content').height();
    }

}

})(jQuery);
```

I've been staring at this for hours and have gone braindead, I think I might be missing something basic.  Would this have anything to do with the CSS?  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the following modifications so that the `isVisible` flag determines whether the panel starts OPEN or CLOSED:

1. Modify the `hidePanel()` function so that we can pass it a flag. The flag determines whether the panel should animate or "snap" shut. This gives us the option to close the menu instantly upon init without any animation.

   ```
   hidePanel: function (snap) {
       $('.panel-wrapper').animate({
           bottom: -(Panel.getAnimationOffset())
       }, (snap ? 0 : Panel.animationDuration), Panel.animationEasing, function () {
           Panel.isVisible = false;
           Panel.updateTabMessage();
       });
   },
   ```
2. Modify the `init()` function to check the `isVisible` flag and "snap" the panel shut if appropriate:

   ```
   init: function () {
       if (!this.isVisible) {
           this.hidePanel(true);
       }
   },
   ```
3. Modify the `togglePanel()` function to pass the "snap" flag to `hidePanel()` as false (do animation):

   ```
   togglePanel: function () {
       ((this.isVisible) ? this.hidePanel(false) : this.showPanel)();
   },
   ```
4. Set the intial `isVisible` value to `false`:

   ```
   isVisible: false,
   ```
5. To start with the panel open, just set the `isVisible` flag to `true`:

   ```
   isVisible: true,
   ```

---

[**EXAMPLE STARTING CLOSED**](http://jsfiddle.net/juu7fvm4/5/)

[**EXAMPLE STARTING OPEN**](http://jsfiddle.net/juu7fvm4/6/)

Comment: Just made these additions to the code, much tidier and displays cleanly.  Thanks for taking the time to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
init : function() {
       this.hidePanel();
},
```

Instead of leaving the init empty.

Comment: Wonderful!  Thank you, although it does show the closing animation when the page is opened, but I'm beyond being bothered by that.  Thank you Phani :)